# Responsive design page for struts tags in jsp page

Tags: jquery, css, struts2

I am trying to creat responsive web page. I tried to align three button as responsive one. I could align normal buttons update and
cancel.But reset button can't be align...it is positioning at different places every time. Any assistance pls?

```
HTML code:

<div class="button-container">
    <button type="button" style="opacity:0.5;cursor:default;"  disabled="disabled" title="Update" id="updPsw">
    <span>Update</span>
    </button>
    <button class="mdclose" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    <s:reset title="Reset"></s:reset>
</div>

CSS:

.button-container{
    position: relative;
    top :20px;
    right: 40px;
}
input[type="reset"] {
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #444;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*   width: 100%; */
    border: 1px solid #3ac162;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
/*  margin-bottom: 10px; */
/*  margin-top: 22px; */
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 42px;
    right: 62px;
}
```

Comment: Struts using theme to generate content, is it what you need?

Comment: Use different theme for S2 tags or use HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using strut tag, used html tags and it worked out

Answer (score 0):

CSS CODE:

```
.button-container{
    position: inherit;
    top :20px;
    right: 40px;
}
input[type="reset"] {
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #444;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*   width: 100%; */
    border: 1px solid #3ac162;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
/*  margin-bottom: 10px; */
/*  margin-top: 22px; */
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 42px;
    right: 62px;
}
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button type="button"vstyle="opacity:0.5;cursor:default;"  disabled="disabled" title="Update" id="updPsw">
    <span>Update</span>
    </button>
    <button class="mdclose" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="mdclose" title="Reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add comments or little explanation along with your code, so that it will be helpful to understand about what you did in your answer :)

Comment: Reset is the struts tag button where they call some struts related stuff over onclick